# One hot encoding with ambiguitiy (nucleotide sequences)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, one-hot-encoding

Nucleotide sequences (or DNA sequences) generally are comprised of 4 bases: ATGC which makes for a very nice, easy and efficient way of encoding this for machine learning purposes.

```
sequence = AAATGCC
ohe_sequence = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

But when you take into account RNA sequences and mistakes that can sometimes occur in sequencing machines, the letters UYRWSKMDVHBXN are added... When one-hot encoding this you end up with a matrix of 17 rows of which the last 13 rows are generally all 0's.

This is very inefficient and does not confer the biological meaning that these extra (ambiguous) letters have.

For example:

- T and U are interchangeable
- Y represents there to be a C or T
- N and X represent there to be any of the 4 bases (ATGC)

And so I have made a dictionary that represents this biological meaning

```
nucleotide_dict = {'A': 'A', 'T':'T', 'U':'T', 'G':'G', 'C':'C', 'Y':['C', 'T'], 'R':['A', 'G'], 'W':['A', 'T'], 'S':['G', 'C'], 'K':['T', 'G'], 'M':['C', 'A'], 'D':['A', 'T', 'G'], 'V':['A', 'G', 'C'], 'H':['A', 'T', 'C'], 'B':['T', 'G', 'C'], 'X':['A', 'T', 'G', 'C'], 'N':['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to make an efficient one-hot-encoding script (or wether there is a way to do this with the scikit learn module) that utilizes this dictionary in order to get a result like this:

```
sequence = ANTUYCC
ohe_sequence = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

# or even better:
ohe_sequence = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0.5, 0, 0.5], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

[image: This figure illustrates the nucleotide ambiguity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fun! I think you can do this using a dictionary with the appropriate values. I added the scikit-learn class because you mentioned you were using that. See the `transform` below:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

nucleotide_dict = {
    "A": [1, 0, 0, 0],
    "G": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "C": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "T": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "U": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "Y": [0, 0, 1, 1],
    "R": [1, 1, 0, 0],
    "W": [1, 0, 0, 1],
    "S": [0, 1, 1, 0],
    "K": [0, 1, 0, 1],
    "M": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    "D": [1, 1, 0, 1],
    "V": [1, 1, 1, 0],
    "H": [1, 0, 1, 1],
    "B": [0, 1, 1, 1],
    "X": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "N": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "-": [0, 0, 0, 0],
}


class NucleotideEncoder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, norm=True):
        self.norm = norm

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        f1 = lambda a: list(a)
        f2 = lambda g: nucleotide_dict[g]
        f3 = lambda c: list(map(f2, f1(c[0])))
        f4 = lambda t: np.array(f3(t)) / np.sum(np.array(f3(t)), axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        f = f3
        if self.norm:
            f = f4
        return np.apply_along_axis(f, 1, X)


samples = np.array([["AAATGCC"], ["ANTUYCC"]])
print(NucleotideEncoder().fit_transform(samples))
```

Output:

```
[[[1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
  [1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
  [1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
  [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]
  [0.   1.   0.   0.  ]
  [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]
  [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]]

 [[1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
  [0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]
  [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]
  [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]
  [0.   0.   0.5  0.5 ]
  [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]
  [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the latter approach, as it more closely corresponds to the real meaning: E.g. `Y` does not mean `C` *and* `T`, but one of `C` *or* `T`. If no further information is available, assuming equal probabilities (i.e. weights) seems reasonable. Of course this non-standard encoding needs to be reflected by the choice of loss function down the road.

To answer your question: You could precompute the mapping from the letters to the encoding and then create an `encode` function that takes a `sequence` as input and returns the encoded sequence as an `(len(sequence), 4)`-shaped `np.array` as follows:

```
import numpy as np

nucleotide_dict = {'A':'A', 'T':'T', 'U':'T', 'G':'G', 'C':'C', 'Y':['C', 'T'], 'R':['A', 'G'], 'W':['A', 'T'], 'S':['G', 'C'], 'K':['T', 'G'], 'M':['C', 'A'], 'D':['A', 'T', 'G'], 'V':['A', 'G', 'C'], 'H':['A', 'T', 'C'], 'B':['T', 'G', 'C'], 'X':['A', 'T', 'G', 'C'], 'N':['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']}
index_mapper = {'A': 0, 'T': 1, 'G': 2, 'C': 3}
mapper_dict = dict()
for k, v in nucleotide_dict.items():
    encoding = np.zeros(4)
    p = 1 / len(v)
    encoding[[index_mapper[i] for i in v]] = p
    mapper_dict[k] = encoding

def encode(sequence):
    return np.array([mapper_dict[s] for s in sequence])
```

This seems to produce the desired result and is probably somewhat efficient.

An example:

```
print(encode('AYSDX'))
```

prints the following:

```
array([[1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.5       , 0.        , 0.5       ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.5       , 0.5       ],
       [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        ],
       [0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      , 0.25      ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version that allows for different length sequences:

```
import numpy as np

nucleotide_dict = {
    "A": [1, 0, 0, 0],
    "G": [0, 1, 0, 0],
    "C": [0, 0, 1, 0],
    "T": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "U": [0, 0, 0, 1],
    "Y": [0, 0, 1, 1],
    "R": [1, 1, 0, 0],
    "W": [1, 0, 0, 1],
    "S": [0, 1, 1, 0],
    "K": [0, 1, 0, 1],
    "M": [1, 0, 1, 0],
    "D": [1, 1, 0, 1],
    "V": [1, 1, 1, 0],
    "H": [1, 0, 1, 1],
    "B": [0, 1, 1, 1],
    "X": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "N": [1, 1, 1, 1],
    "-": [0, 0, 0, 0],
}

norm = True
samples = np.array(["AAATGCC", "ANTUYCC", "".join(list(nucleotide_dict.keys()))[:-1]])


def nucleotide_encode(samples, norm=True):
    m = map(list, samples)
    f1 = lambda x: np.array(list(map(nucleotide_dict.get, x)))
    f = f1
    if norm:
        f = lambda x: np.nan_to_num(f1(x) / np.sum(f1(x), axis=1)[:, np.newaxis])
    return list(map(f, m))


for i, j in zip(samples, nucleotide_encode(samples, norm=norm)):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Yields:

```
AAATGCC
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
ANTUYCC
[[1.   0.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25]
 [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.   1.  ]
 [0.   0.   0.5  0.5 ]
 [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   1.   0.  ]]
AGCTUYRWSKMDVHBXN
[[1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         1.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         1.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         1.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.5        0.5       ]
 [0.5        0.5        0.         0.        ]
 [0.5        0.         0.         0.5       ]
 [0.         0.5        0.5        0.        ]
 [0.         0.5        0.         0.5       ]
 [0.5        0.         0.5        0.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.         0.33333333]
 [0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.         0.33333333 0.33333333]
 [0.         0.33333333 0.33333333 0.33333333]
 [0.25       0.25       0.25       0.25      ]
 [0.25       0.25       0.25       0.25      ]]
```